# Surface reference faster than Surface object

Tags: cuda

I recently changed the surface reference of my algorithm for a surface object. Then, I noticed that the program runs slower.

Here is a comparison for simple example where I fill a 3D floating array [400*400*400] with a constant value.

#### Surface reference API

Time: 9.068928 ms

```
surface<void, cudaSurfaceType3D> s_volumeSurf;
...
surf3Dwrite(value, s_volumeSurf, px*sizeof(float), py, pz, cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
```

#### Surface object API

Time: 14.960256 ms

```
cudaSurfaceObject_t l_volSurfObj;
...
surf3Dwrite(value, l_volSurfObj, px*sizeof(float), py, pz, cudaBoundaryModeTrap);
```

This was tested on a GTX 680 with Compute Capability 3.0 and CUDA 5.0.

Does anyone have an explanation for this difference?

Comment: How did you run your benchmark?

Comment: I did it with cudaEvent (cudaEventRecord, cudaEventSynchronize and cudaEventElapsedTime)

Comment: The problem remains on CUDA 5.5 ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the surface object case, surface descriptors are fetched from global memory.
In the surface reference case, these descriptors are compiled into constant memory. Fetching these descriptors may be much faster than global memory access. If your kernel is small enough or L1 cache is disabled, you could observe significant performance loss.

You can diff the SASS code to see the difference.

Comment: So, would you say that it's generally recommended to stick with surface references instead?  When would using a surface object be preferable?